# How to use Union Types Protobuf C++

Tags: c++, oop, protocol-buffers

I am new in using Protobuf. I have a server client communication (UDP) in C++. Now I use Protobuf to send a message which contains some Information to the Server.

```
package Test;
message vName{
required  int32 name = 1;
}

message vNat{
required  int32 nat = 1;
}

message vTan{
required int32 tan = 1;
}
message Test{
enum Type { vName = 1; vNAT = 2; vTAN = 3;}

required Type  type = 1;

optional vName name = 2;
optional vNat  nat  = 2;
optional vTan  tan = 2;
}
```

---

Now i want only send the Information which is set. For example Type is 1. Then how can i access or set the name?

Can anybody make an small snippet that i can understand how to use it?

I apologize for my english skills :D

**Protobuf version: 2.5.0**

**OS: Windows**
**Enviroment: Visual Studio**

**Language: C++**

From https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#union
You may also want to have an enum field that identifies which message is filled in, so that you can switch on it:

```
message OneMessage {
enum Type { FOO = 1; BAR = 2; BAZ = 3; }

// Identifies which field is filled in.
required Type type = 1;

// One of the following will be filled in.
optional Foo foo = 2;
optional Bar bar = 3;
optional Baz baz = 4;
}
```

How can I use this in the Code? I think this is what I want. Have anybody an idea where i can find an example?

Comment: *"Can anybody make an small snippet that i can understand how to use it? "* Unlikely that this will happen: SO is not code writing service. I suggest that you try to do this yourself first, and then ask if you encourter a specific problem.

Comment: @George your right. it was my fault

Comment: First at  all thank everybody who takes the time to help me. @user694733: the problem is that i didnt understand how to use something like this. I have a lot of messages and i dont want to send everytime the hole message only the message which is set in the client side. In the proto file i have a message which contains vname, vnat,... as optional. But my goal not to send the hole message only the message which is  be set in the client side. I hope i could explain my problem :D.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#oneof), instead of using optional fields and a workaround-enum.